# getting links from table in web page

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to go to a website, use their search tool to query a database, and grab all of the links from the table of search results displayed below the search tool. The problem is, the source for the website only shows the html for the search tool. Can anyone help me figure out how to get the links from the table? The address of the search tool is:

https://wagyu.digitalbeef.com/

I was hoping to use BeautifulSoup and python 3.6 on a windows 10 machine to read the pages associated with those links and grab the name of the cows and it's parents to create a more advanced pedigree chart than what is available on the site. Thanks for the help.

Just to clarify, I can manually grab a single link, use bs to grab the html for that page, and pull out the pedigree info. I just don't know how to grab the links from the search results page.

Comment: That is a particularly sophisticated page. It uses javascript to compile an xml document from the submitted form and sends that to the server which then returns a table which, if you could get it into BeautifulSoup would be a doddle to scrape. May I suggest you look at adding selenium.webcriver to your toolkit?

Comment: Thanks for your comment Paula. I will dig into this some more and see what I can do with selenium.webdriver tonight. Please correct me if I am wrong...I am new to working with web pages. It looks like I can get the links I need by inspecting the web elements, which beautiful soup doesn't do. Can you give me any pointers on how to do that w/ Selenium? I will use it with Java.

Comment: Firstly I don't use java. C, C++, python yes, java no. You manually use, e.g., Chrome's  Web Developer extension to pick up individual links, you cannot unless you can either generate the xml and pass it to the appropriate api or call the javascript routine programmatically get all the appropriate links.